# Javascript React Promises

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i have probably a small trouble.
Here is a function that returns a Promise.

```
export default ()=>{
    const socket = io(config.crypt_compare_api_url);
    let subscription = config.subscription;
    socket.emit('SubAdd', { subs: subscription });

    return new Promise(resolve => {
        socket.on("m",resolve);
    });
}
```

And a here i use it. It's imported as get_crypto

```
get_crypto().then((parsedData)=>{
            let el=this.state.currencies.find(element=> element.name===parsedData.name);
            if(el)
            {
                el.price=parsedData.price;
            }
            else this.state.currencies.push(parsedData);

            this.setState(  {
                currencies: this.state.currencies
            });
        });
```

** **'then'** function always have to repeat after socket gets a message. But it works only one time,**

Comment: Using a promise is not suitable for your use case. A promise is only resolved and evaluated to a value once. You need an observable like pattern. Can you show us where get_crypto() is being called. I am assuming this is a react project based on the question tag. Please put up your code so that we can help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot recall then callback multiple times. You should use observable or just call a callback on 'm' event:

```js
export const getCrypto = (cb) => {
    const socket = io(config.crypt_compare_api_url);
    let subscription = config.subscription;
    socket.emit('SubAdd', { subs: subscription });
    socket.on("m", cb);
}

import { getCrypto } from 'get-crypto.js';

getCrypto(parsedData => {
  console.log(parsedData);
  // Do something with parsed data
})
```

Comment: could you make some example

Comment: or i can give you sample

Comment: i did this
 get_crypto(
            (parsedData)=>{
                let el=this.state.currencies.find(element=> element.name===parsedData.name);
                if(el)
                {
                    el.price=parsedData.price;
                }
                else this.state.currencies.push(parsedData);

                this.setState(  {
                    currencies: this.state.currencies
                });
        });

Comment: but i dont think it's the best practice

Comment: Why shouldnt it be best practice?

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to call `get_crypto()` again to get a new promise, so you could do something like this:

```
const datahandler = function(parsedData){
   let el=this.state.currencies.find(element=> element.name===parsedData.name);
   if(el)
     {
         el.price=parsedData.price;
     }
   else this.state.currencies.push(parsedData);

   this.setState(  {
       currencies: this.state.currencies
    });
    }

const loop = function(){
        get_crypto().then(datahandler).then(loop);
    }

loop();
```